# GCP VM Instance is not able to access secrets from Secret Manager despite of appropriate Roles

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, service-accounts, google-secret-manager

I created few secrets in GCP's `Secret Manager` service. Then to access those secrets on my local machine I created a `service account` and a `JSON` key to authenticate that service account from my local machine. I also granted the role `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` to that service account to enable it to access the values of secrets from `Secret Manager`. Now, it is working perfectly fine on my local machine.

Further, I want to deploy this code to the GCP `Compute Instance`. Hence, I created one and shipped the source code to that instance. I also granted the same permission `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` to the default service account of compute instance. Now, when I run try this code on the instance it returns me an error of permission denied as stated below.

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
ibdax            | 
ibdax            | Traceback (most recent call last):
ibdax            |   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
ibdax            |     main()
ibdax            |   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
ibdax            |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
ibdax            |     utility.execute()
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute
ibdax            |     settings.INSTALLED_APPS
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
ibdax            |     self._setup(name)
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
ibdax            |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
ibdax            |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
ibdax            |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ibdax            |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
ibdax            |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
ibdax            |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ibdax            |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
ibdax            |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
ibdax            |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ibdax            |   File "/ibdax/ibdax/settings.py", line 19, in <module>
ibdax            |     from ibdax.constants import (
ibdax            |   File "/ibdax/ibdax/constants.py", line 30, in <module>
ibdax            |     DEV_DATABASE_HOST=secrets.get_secrets("dev-database-host")
ibdax            |   File "/ibdax/ibdax/gcp_secret_manager.py", line 23, in get_secrets
ibdax            |     response = self.client.access_secret_version(request)
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/secretmanager_v1/services/secret_manager_service/client.py", line 1155, in access_secret_version
ibdax            |     response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
ibdax            |     return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
ibdax            |     on_error=on_error,
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
ibdax            |     return target()
ibdax            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 75, in error_remapped_callable
ibdax            |     six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
ibdax            |   File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
ibdax            | google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

I checked the IAM role for `Compute Instance's` service account and it has some message which I am not able to understand. Here is the screenshot of that -

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, please don't download a JSON service account key file to your local machine. You can install the `gcloud` command line tool at https://cloud.google.com/sdk and then authenticate via your user account:

```
$ gcloud auth login && gcloud auth application-default login
```

This will prompt you to login to your Google account via the web - no service account required. This is much better from a security and auditing perspective.

---

Similarly, when running on GCE (or any "compute-based" platform like GKE, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, etc), you should create a service account and run the instance as that service account. **Do not use the Default Compute Engine service account!**. Furthermore, do not give the Default Compute Engine service account permission to access all secrets, as this poses a significant security risk. Please see more information at [Secret Manager Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/best-practices).

---

The default OAuth scopes for GCE do not include `cloud-platform`. You need to update the scopes to include `cloud-platform`:

```
$ gcloud compute instances set-service-account "my-instance" --service-account "...@..." --scopes "cloud-platform"
```

More [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes).

Answer (score -1):

Firstly try to troubleshoot
if it is showing network issue then add new firewall rule for your instance give name as allow-ingress-from-iap and select ipv4 source range as your vm ip then in tcp giv 22,3389 then add iam for iap tunnel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).